# how to change v-btn's content programmatically?

Tags: vue.js

In a Vue project with Vuetify, there is a button with a label "click me", what I want is when the button is clicked, its label is changed to "clicked".

I tried , but the button is blank.

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    submit() {
    // How shoud I do?
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<v-btn @click="submit">click me</v-btn>
```

Comment: Sorry,this is my first time asking question here.
I tried '<v-btn v-model="label"></v-btn>', but the button is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is save the content of the label in your components data and change this property in your submit method. Then just change your template to use this data instead of a static label like so:

Your Component:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      label: 'Click me'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.label = 'Something else'
    }
  }
}
```

Your template:

```
<v-btn @click="submit">{{ label }}</v-btn>
```

I highly suggest you read through the [official vue tutorial](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) as all of this is covered within the first paragraphs.